# How long do I have to wait before bandits take over Helgen Keep?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I recently started a new playthrough of Skyrim, and I want to get the archery skillbook in Helgen Keep.  According to the wiki, that skillbook doesn't show up until bandits take over the keep.  How long do I have to wait (I just completed "Unbound") until that happens, so I can kill the bandits, get the skillpoints from them, and get the skillbook?

Answer (score 1):

[The Helgen entry on Fandom](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Helgen#Background) is - as is often the case - not particularly clear about it:

> A few in-game days following the events, a small group of bandits will occupy the ruins of the town (the lock on either gate must be picked, or one of the bandits can open it).

But on [the Gamesas forum](http://www.gamesas.com/what-have-make-helgen-bandits-spawn-t334266.html) some theories are proffered, among which:

> - I just took a quick look in the Creation Kit, and it seems like all you need is to have visited Whiterun at le[a]st 4 days [?] after escaping from Helgen.

> - [The bandits] respawn every 3 in-game days.

More ideas can be found on the [UESP discussion on the topic](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Helgen_Keep#State_of_Helgen_Keep_after_Unbound), and having to finish [the Dragon Rising quest](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon_Rising) shows up again. However, that quest requires you to visit Whiterun, so just the visit could still be the requirement.
In fact, this is corroborated by [its last entry](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Helgen_Keep#Reconfirming_some_things):

> The bandits take over after you visit Whiterun (marking it discovered on your map, you don't need to finish or even start Dragon Rising), you don't need to wait for a cell reset to trigger the first bandit occupation.

I currently don't have Skyrim installed or I would have tested it, but this seems credible: **visit Whiterun and return immediately (or possibly wait for 3 in-game days).**

Comment: I tried discovering Whiterun and going back, and it didn't work.  I'll try again after Dragon Rising.

Comment: @Tyll'a Can you test the following? It seems the following requirements need to have been met before the bandits show up: #1. You have returned to Helgen (from outside of the exterior area) at least once #2. Whiterun needs to have been discovered #3. At least 3 in-game days need to have passed, of which at least one after having returned to Helgen.

Comment: @Tyll'a By the way: are you using any mods?

Comment: No, not using any mods.